# Сокращенное тернарное условие на js

Tags: javascript

На php (пхп ваще вот это всё извращенцы) есть возможность написать тернарное условие следующего типа:

```
$a=1;

echo $a>1?:'Я вру';
```

Есть ли что-то подобное в js?

Например конкретно хочу получить следующее:

Есть `localStorage["mycar"]="Маруся";`

И я хочу вывести значение `localStorage["mycar"]` если оно есть, если нет, то что-то другое.

Как я делаю:

```
alert(localStorage["mycar"]?localStorage["mycar"]:'Нету такого');
```

А можно ли написать что-то типо такого, чтобы сократить запись:

```
alert(localStorage["mycar"]?:'Нету такого');
```

Comment: Оператор `||` или новый оператор `??`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen и как мне это впихать сюда alert(localStorage["mycar"]?:'Нету такого') ?   Я пытаюсь сократить запись, как можно короче.

Comment: @porshen.vip Вместо `?:` написать  `??`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Действительно работает как надо. Спасибо. Я просто еще впихал туда двоеточие из-за этого у меня не работало)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать ?? или || на проверку null или undefined

Например:

```
let a = 'Value' ?? false
```

И если значение 'a' пустое то значение станет false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/353446/

Comment: Четко, спасибо. Работает система

Comment: Обращайся.....)